# Freelan: Invalid route metric

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn

I'm trying to setup a P2P VPN using [freelan](http://freelan.org), it worked in a virtualbox environment but when setting up the actual network I'm running into some issues. It seems either something is misconfigured or I've run into a bug. Either way I don't know how to proceed and it would be great if someone could help me! When trying to setup the connection one of my nodes gives the following output.

```
[IMPORTANT] Session established with <ip>
[INFORMATION] Cipher suite: ecdhe_rsa_aes256_gcm_sha384
[INFORMATION] Elliptic curve: sect571k1
[ERROR] Fatal exception occurred in thread #1: Invalid route metric
[INFORMATION] Tap adapter's thread is now stopped.
[INFORMATION] Closing FSCP server...
[IMPORTANT] Execution stopped.
```

The configuration of this node is as follows

```
[fscp]
listen_on=0.0.0.0:12000
contact=<ip of other node>

[tap_adapter]
ipv4_address_prefix_length=10.0.0.2/24
dhcp_proxy_enabled=yes
dhcp_server_ipv4_address_prefix_length=10.0.0.0/24

[security]
signature_certificate_file=crt.crt
signature_private_key_file=key.key
authority_certificate_file=ca.crt
```

The other node is giving me the follow (non problematic) output:

```
[IMPORTANT] Session established with <ip>.
[INFORMATION] Cipher suite: ecdhe_rsa_aes256_gcm_sha384
[INFORMATION] Elliptic curve: sect571k1
[INFORMATION] Added system route: wlo1 - <ip> => 192.168.0.1 - metric 0
[IMPORTANT] Session with <ip> lost (timeout).
[INFORMATION] Removed system route: wlo1 - <ip> => 192.168.0.1 - metric 0
```

Output of `uname -a` on the problematic node: 
`Linux ubuntu 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 21 17.24.18 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64  GNU/Linux`

it's running `ubuntu 16.10`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used freelan, so take my advice with some caution, but I think the error message *Invalid route metric* is highly revealing.

When is a route metric an embarrassment? Suppose yo do not have a route to site A, then setting a route to it with whichever metric cannot possibly be a problem. Now suppose you already have a route to site A, when is it a problem to add another route to it **with a different metric**? Never, of course, it just means you changed your mind. So when is the metric a problem? When the route already exists, with the **same** metric, because the kernel then cannot distinguish between the two routing table entries.

Hence your problem is that the route to your twin site already exists, and it has not been clearly torn down the last time you exited freelan. So you may try, **before** starting it, to see whether your routing table has an entry like this,

```
11.22.33.44 via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0 metric 100
```

and if it does, you tear it down,

```
sudo ip route del 11.22.33.44 via 192.168.73.1 dev eth0 metric 100
```

and **only** then you start (or restart) your freelan. Should this work, it should be trivial to script it.

Just for the sake of completeness, this *forgetfulness* seems common, OpenVPN always leaves in my routing table exactly the route above, after disconnection.